# Progressively load embedded youtube videos

Tags: jquery, youtube

I have 10 or so YouTube videos embedded on a page and landing on that page and then attempting to scroll down initially nothing happens as the videos are all loading then 10s or so later you can scroll.

Does anyone know if a jQ plugin such as http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/ or some other approach will allow off screen videos to load only when scrolled to making the initial page experience much more responsive?

Cheers for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution may be to display the thumbnails of the Youtube image and then "pop-up" an embedded video when one is clicked on.  Example: http://cooldisplays.net/index.php?page=single&id=1

To get the thumbnail of the image see: [How do I get a YouTube video thumbnail from the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-to-get-thumbnail-of-youtube-video-link-using-youtube-api)

There are multiple ways to pop-up an embedded video including the prettyPhoto library. (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/